# &nbsp; in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I need to do something like:

```
paper.text(Left, Top, " " + this._p.Label + ":");
paper.text(Left, Top, "&nbsp;" + this._p.Label + ":");
```

But the prepended whitespace won't show or show as `&nbsp;` in text.

I've tried:

```
label.attr({"xml:space": "preserve"});
```

...with no effect.

Is there anyway to access the SVG node in Raphael JS so I can set

```
setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace","space","preserve");
```

(or is there any other way to solve this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely apply that namespaced attribute directly to the SVG element managed by Raphael.  It's this simple:

```
paper.canvas.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace", "xml:space","preserve");
```

Demonstrated to be functional [here](http://voidblossom.com/testTextSpacing.php).

Comment: Thanks! You are awesome! Do you also know how to acess induvidual SVG elements?

Comment: I'm not that awesome -- I learned the answer to this question by asking it in a different form elsewhere =) In any case, you can access the svg elements associated with a Raphael object by referencing `element.node`.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Although this seems somewhat <sup>[1]</sup> solved, I came across [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/l_qCMRJIw50) about the same issue, which rather suggests replacing spaces with `\u00a0`. This can easily be achieved by using the string function `.replace(/ /g,'\u00a0')`.

---

**<sup>1</sup>** The leading spaces of the text node in the given link does not work for Mac Safari v.6.0.5. I'm not sure how it looks in other browsers and OS'es.