# How can I output text with blank lines in Raphael

Tags: raphael

I want to place a text in Raphael which contains also blank lines. If there is only one blank line, i can replace "\n\n" by "\n \n" and the blank lines show up.

But if there are multiple blank lines, it does not work.

for example

```
paper.text(100,100, "this\n \n \nblank\nline")
```

does not yield **two** blank lines between "this" and "blank"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add double "new line" characters when using the \`text\` method in Raphael.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145961/how-to-add-double-new-line-characters-when-using-the-text-method-in-raphael)

Comment: yes it is. I was using the search before, but could not find it. sorry.